# Custom php.ini per-directory (for testing sites)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, customization, php

I'm running Apache 2.26, on Windows 7 with PHP 5.39 mod_ssl/2.2.6 OpenSSL/0.9.8g .

PHP works fine, so does Apache.

However, I want to try and create custom php.ini files per directory, for my test sites.

I could - and did - use php_flag but would like to try to create a custom php.ini file that works. I tried to Google this, but couldn't find anything relevant.

This is my current .htaccess for C:/www/vhosts/localhost/testsite1:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php


#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_fileNAME} !\.php -f
#RewriteRule .* index.php

AddType text/html .asp
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .page

php_value include_path "./php:/php/"
```

Yet, I made a change in the custom php.ini within the php to have short tags off [for testing only] but it didn't pick it up, the php code showed instead.

Any help is appreciated with this; it'll be extremely useful!

(bear in mind, this Apache install is a development/testing one)

Comment: Which server API (SAPI) are you using? If FCGI look for user.ini files.

Comment: I'm not using PHP CGI, according to php_sapi_name.  20090626 is my current API.

Comment: I have no idea about that API that more looks like a day than an API. Maybe you missed some line?

Comment: how do I find the API? php_sapi_name was what I tried.

Comment: Yeah that's normally it. No idea what happens there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `php_flag` then you are probably using mod_php5.  Custom 'php.ini' files aren't supported with this.  You would need to use suPHP or equiv as the `php.ini` is only loaded at PHP startup, and this isn't *per-request* for mod_php5 and FCGI.

*However*, since you are using PHP 5.3 you can also use [.user.ini files](http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) which are parsed on a per-request basis.

Comment: .user.ini : *"These files are processed **only** by the CGI/FastCGI SAPI."*

Comment: @hakre, sorry, yup you're right. The hit a sweep-spot for FCGI. If the OP wants to use mod_php5 on a WAMP config then the easiest way to debug this is in a separate VM

Comment: @hakre, For apache we can use .htaccess per directory to specify php variables/config.

Comment: @TerryE, Also, please elaborate on the "suPHP" option.

Comment: suPHP isn't an option for the end developer. It's a choice for the sysadmin when configuring the webserver, and one that is mostly deprecated these days.

Answer (score 1):

Many times you might feel that you require a different settings for different sites (running on the  same server) as specified in php.ini . So you start making changes in your php files using ini_set() or .htaccess to override those settings. In this howto, I will tell you how to solve this problem of having different php settings by having separate php.ini files for each website.

So, lets assume that I have a website with document root as /var/www/html/example/ with domain as  www.example.com. For testing purpose you can create a small file in /var/www/html/example/phpinfo.php

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Now run http://example.com/phpinfo.php it will display current php settings.

Now copy the php.ini file from /etc/php.ini file to your /var/www/html/example.

[root]# cp /etc/php.ini /var/www/html/example #For fedora users

[chia]$ sudo cp /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini /var/www/example # for Debian and Ubuntu

And now, we just need a simple trick to tell apache where to find the php settings for this website. You need to make this small change in the configuration file.

```
<VirtualHost 10.24.11.2:80>

ServerName example.com

ServerAlias www.example.com

PHPINIDir /var/www/html/example

</VirtualHost>
```

PHPINIDir should be the directory where the file php.ini resides.

Restart the apache after this

[root]# service httpd restart  # for Fedora/Redhat/CenOS based systems

[chia]$ sudo apache2 restart  # for Debian/Ubuntu based systems

Comment: This changes it for all virtualhosts though, confusing enough. So it's not a good way.